# -framework command line option in cmake

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, vtk

I am trying to compile some c++ code that was already written (by someone else) using Cmake in Linux, and I came across the line `SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-framework OpenGL")` in `CMakeLists.txt`. I've never seen `-framework` as a command line option and can't seem to find any mention of it in any posts/websites/cmake documentation. And, of course, I am getting the errors `c++: error: OpenGL: No such file or directory` and `c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-framework'`.

Does anyone know what -framework does? Cmake was having problems with OpenGL when I was trying to use it to build/configure VTK, but I thought I fixed that since it ended up working. Would it make sense for the VTK build to work and not this? Could the unrecognized -framework option error be a result of the lack of OpenGL? Or are they separate?

Comment: This seems specific to Apple http://chaitanyav.github.io/2014/07/13/getting-starting-with-opengl/

Comment: Yes, `-framework` is Mac OS. Frameworks are like a more elaborate library mechanism. In addition to the libraries themselves, they can also contain headers, resources, etc. They can also be versioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-framework` option is accepted by Apple `clang`; frameworks are a way of packaging headers and libraries in a particular directory structure.

A CMake file unconditionally specifying those options is not portable; a better solution that will work cross-platform is to use the `find_package` command.  You can read more about how to use `find_package` [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's a find_package command that would function the same way as the -framework option, or is that not possible? I don't feel like I understand the inner workings of -framework well enough to know how to use find_package to accomplish the same thing